# How to solve least square quadratic problem using FFT

Tags: optimization, quadratics, fourier-transform, fast-fourier-transform

Let A, B, C and D be some matrix and x be a vector, I want to solve the following optimization problem:

$$
\min_x \| Ax -B\|^2_2 + \| Cx-D\|^2_2
$$
my solution:

$$
J = \| Ax -B\|^2_2 + \| Cx-D\|^2_2
$$

$$
\frac{\partial J}{\partial x} = 2A^T(Ax -B) + 2C^T(Cx-D) = 0
$$

so, 
$$
x = (A^TA+C^TC)^{-1}(A^TB+C^TD)
$$

But in some literature, I see the authors use FFT to solve such problems.

My questions are: 
1) How one can use FFT to solve the above problem? 
2) What is the advantage to use FFT?

Thanks.

Comment: [I have closed the same question you asked on DSP.SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/44670/how-to-solve-least-square-quadratic-problem-using-fft).  This site might be a better fit for it, but let me know one way or the other.